# FancyHdr header problem

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have tried many different methods to solve this, by I can´t figure it out. Why is it when using fancyhdr that my header isn't parallel with the text. My code is included, thanks for the help

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead {Skråplan Eksperimentet}
\rhead {side \thepage \hspace{1pt} af \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

%forside
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\large Københavns Universitet}\\[1.5 cm]

\textsc{\large Først lab, Niels Bohr Institutet}\\[0.5 cm]

%title

\HRule \\[0.4 cm]

{\huge\bfseries Skråplan eksperimentet\\[0.4 cm]}

\HRule \\[0.4 cm]

%forfatter

\textsc{\large Forfatter}\\[1 cm]
\textsc{\ Morten Sode, Kasper Tølløse og Helle Kogsbøll Leerberg}

\vfill
\textsc{\ Afleveret: 11 December 2014}\\[0.3 cm]

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%introduktion



\textbf{\large Introduktion}\\[0.3 cm]






%Metode
\textbf{\large Metode}\\[0.3 cm]



%Resultater
\textbf{\large Resultater}\\[0.3 cm]


%diskussion
\textbf{\large Diskussion}\\[0.3 cm]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's perfectly parallel for me. A problem with the viewer, maybe?

Comment: That may correct, by then a different question. How can i get the \large text here it would be the "induktion" centered to the left?

Comment: Btw, welcome to TeX SX! I don't quite get what you mean in your  comment. What is thet ‘induktion’?

Comment: I just meant: where does it appear in  your code. Is it centred section titles in ‘ large’ size that you want?

Comment: You are not setting section headers by hand, do you?

Answer (score 0):

A very smart girl came over, and the answer was to make a \noindent code, thereby it was a very basis human error on my side